# Trace inequality for matrices with determinant 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues, traces

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices with $\det(A)=\det(B)=1$. Does it follow that

$\sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(A^TB^TBA-I)}\le\sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(A^TA-I)}+\sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(B^TB-I)}$

I suspect that this can be shown using the singular value decomposition, but I've not been able to write a proof yet. Scaling arguments suggest that the determinant condition is really needed.

If needed, it may be assumed that all singular values of both $A$ and $B$ are positive.

Comment: Are the trace operators missing under the square roots on the right? (My guess would be that they are but I'll leave it to the OP to edit them in).

Comment: Anyway, looking at the sheer size, the claim seems fishy: let $A=B$ be the diagonal matrix with the entries $x,1/x$ on the diagonal. Then the LHS is about $x^2$ and the right hand side is about $2x$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: It seems that the question can be "fixed" but since the OP has not edited the question despite fedja's countex, I'm not sure if this fix would be of interest....

Comment: @Suvrit: How would you fix this? I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per fedja's comment, the version of the inequality written in the question does not hold. A version that does hold is given below.

$\newcommand{\trace}{\mathrm{tr}}$
   Define $\trace_n(X) := \frac{1}{n}\trace(X)$ be the normalized trace. Let $U, V$ be unitary matrices. Then, the following inequality can be shown to hold
\begin{equation*}
  \sqrt{1-|\trace_n(UV)|^2} \le \sqrt{1-|\trace_n(U)|^2} + \sqrt{1-|\trace_n(V)|^2},
\end{equation*}
with equality if and only if $U$ or $V$ is a unitary scalar matrix.

For an elementary proof, please see the paper: ["A trace inequality for unitary matrices"](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2974909?uid=3739560&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21101262726543) by B.-Y. Wang and F. Zhang (AMM, 101(5), 1994).

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. Any chance that something can be done if $U$ or $V$ have an eigenvalue not on the unit circle?

Comment: @Martijn: I had once obtained the above ineq. as a special case of something else; if i recall the context, i'll update the answer. some reasonable generalization is certainly possible because the above ineq. is really just the triangle ineq. in disguise.

Comment: Wang-Zhang's inequality was revisited in my little note: Remarks on Krein’s Inequality http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00283-011-9270-z